# How do we calculate the expectation of the exponential of a matrix with normally distributed entries?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-differential-equations

Suppose we have a matrix
$$
M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & -\Delta \omega  & 0 \\
 \Delta \omega  & -\gamma  & \bar{\omega } \\
 0 & -\bar{\omega } & -\gamma  \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with $\lambda, \bar{\omega}, \Delta \omega \in \mathbb{R}$.
It is perhaps worth noting that the matrix can equivalently be defined as acting on a vector $v$ to produce a vector $Mv$ given by
$$
Mv = v \times \left( \bar{\omega}, 0, -\Delta\omega \right) - \gamma \left(1 - \hat{x} \hat{x}^T\right)v
$$
where $\times$ is the cross product and $\hat{x} = \left(1,0,0\right)$.

If a vector $v(t)$ is governed by the equation
$$
\dot{v}=M v
$$
we have the solution
$$
v(t) = e^{M(t-t_o)}v_o
$$
for some initial condition $v_o = v(t_o)$.
Practically the solution can be computed by determining the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $M$.

Now suppose that $\Delta \omega$ is normally distributed about zero with a standard deviation $\sigma_{\Delta \omega}$. My question is: does the expectation value of $v(t)$ admit a relatively simple solution, say, in the form of
$$
\langle v(t) \rangle = e^{M'(t-t_o)}v_o
$$
for some matrix $M'$ that is a function of $\sigma_{\Delta \omega}$?

So far I can see that we have

$$
\langle v(t) \rangle = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(t-t_o)^n \langle M^n \rangle}{n!} v_o
$$

but it is not clear to me if the infinite sum simplifies, or if the special form of $M$ enjoys any simplifications.